# Conditionally render template text as bold

Tags: html, jsf, conditional-rendering

For my inbox page,  in this page user will be able to see messages, message will have 2 types of state ( Not yet started, In_progress)..

dataTable where user will be able to see all messages will have 3 columns:

```
Data, title, actions
```

State of messages comes from services. My task is, to add **BOLDED** word "**NEW**" to the title of every message that user hadn't opened yet.

After opening, state will change to "in_progress" and bolded word "**NEW**" should disapear.

Or there is idea insted of **NEW** to use some kind of icon.

What I have done so far is :

```
<p:column headerText="#{msg.title}">
    <h:outputText value="#{task.properties.bpm_status=='Not Yet Started'?'New ':''}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{task.properties.bpm_description}" />
</p:column>
```

Problem is, I can't correctly add `<b></b>` to bold it or to add icon instead.

I've tried to add `<b></b>` arround 'New' but I get error in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<ui:fragment>` to conditionally render template text.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{task.properties.bpm_status eq 'Not Yet Started'}">
    <b>New</b>
</ui:fragment>
```

Alternatively, apply a style class.

```
<h:outputText value="New" styleClass="new" rendered="#{task.properties.bpm_status eq 'Not Yet Started'}" />
```

```
.new {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Using inline styles via `style` attribute is poor practice as it isn't abstract/reusable.

Comment: Why Google couldn't give me this... :)

Thanks, worked fine. !

Answer (score 2):

try to use the following style in  `"style="font-weight:bold""` in  h:outputText Tag

```
 <h:outputText value="#{task.properties.bpm_status=='Not Yet Started'?'New ':''}" style="font-weight:bold"  />
```

I tried it and it`s work for me